# Script to send email when a cell value is changed automatically by GOOGLEFINANCE function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers, google-finance

I have a column of values that pulls data from GoogleFinance using the =GOOGLEFINANCE function in Google Sheets. When the function is working, the column will return a series of figures. Occasionally, there is an error with GOOGLEFINANCE and the cells in the column will return N/A or other error messages.

I want to generate an email to be sent whenever one of the cells in this column returns an error. The only scripts I can find are triggered by manual edits to cells. How can I generate an email when the change is made automatically through the operation of the GOOGLEFINANCE function?